# Problem with uploading system using firestorage

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am facing a problem while uploading file from my winForm to firestorage.
the uploading progress has been stopped before it is finished without giving any error but that happened only with files that have more than 10 megabyte size and i don't know the reasons.
here is my code

```
DialogResult result = uploadFile.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            FileStream stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open);
            var task = new FirebaseStorage(".......com")
            .Child("Anas")
            .Child("12")
            .Child("4")
            .PutAsync(stream);
            task.Progress.ProgressChanged += (s, c) => Console.WriteLine($"Progress: {c.Percentage} %");
            var downloadUrl = await task;
```

Comment: I bet if you wrapped this in a try catch you would be able to get the actual error.

Comment: i tried that but  there is no error but it is not uploading the files theat have a size higher then 10 megabbytes

Comment: Can you show us the code with the try catch?

Comment: i added a try and i putted all the above code insde it and i used Exception with catch and printed it in messagebox (i didn't know how to post a code as comment )

Comment: This is a 3rd party port to.net, if you have a bug i suggest letting them know on github.